# AsyncTask to update ui counter which is invoked in other class in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-thread

I need to update file upload count dynamically into Ui progressbar which is invoked in other class method. How can communicate between AsyncTask doInBackground() and myClass.uploadFiles(). please help me

this is activity

```
  public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private ProgressDialog dialog = null;
        String status;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_file);
            
              CounteTask task = new CounteTask();
              task.execute();
            
        }

            private class CounteTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {


                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

                    try {

                        status = myClass.uploadFiles(MyActivity.this);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void resultGetlogin) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Sync_Records.this, "", "Please wait, file count..");
                }

                protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                    
                }

            }
  }
```

MyClass.java from here need to update ui thread.

```
        public void MyClass{
        
            public static String uploadFiles(Context context) {
            
                  for (count=0 ; count <= 10; count++) {
                     try {
                            upload(count);                            //need to show each count of file which is currently uploading

                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
            
            }
            return status;
        
        }
```

Comment: `public void myClass` Please adhere to java convention starting class names with a capital. Your code is dificult to read now. `public void MyClass`

Comment: A simple solution would be to put the for loop in doInBackground and then call MyClass.uploadFile(count).

Comment: Thank  you. That i can do. But i want exactly the above flow. So any other way.